# select consequence row with changing data

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

sample data

```
Name StartDate  Event
Ali 1/7/2010    garage
Ali 1/8/2010    garage
Ali 1/9/2010    garage
Ali 1/10/2010   aircond
Ali 1/11/2010   aircond
Ali 1/12/2010   aircond
Ali 1/13/2010   aircond
Ali 1/14/2010   garage
Ali 1/15/2010   yard
Ali 1/16/2010   dock
Ali 1/17/2010   dock
```

expected

```
Name    Start Date  Event
Ali 1/7/2010    garage
Ali 1/10/2010   aircond
Ali 1/14/2010   garage
Ali 1/15/2010   yard
Ali 1/16/2010   dock
```

Dear experts,

I have a question. I need to design a query such it will only pickup if there is changes in the Event column like what I have in the expected table.Can you please advise me how to do this in sql oracle?

Comment: you can use  break on Event skip 1 it will call break on when event change but selecting only top row for that event change is difficult

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simplified variation of Alex Poole's LAG query:

```
select name, startdate, event
from
 (
    select name, startdate, event,
       case
          when event = 
             lag(event) over (partition by name order by startdate) 
          then 0 --same event
          else 1 --different event or no previous event 
       end as flag
    from t42
 )
where flag = 1
order by name, startdate, event;
```

[fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/32901/5/0)

Comment: I prefer to be able to include the first result explicitly with `lag_event is null` rather than relying on it not matching with `=`, and find the extra subquery a little clearer for that; but that's just me *8-)

Answer (score 1):

This is a 'gaps and islands' problem.

You could use a subquery and the `lag` analytic function to look back the previous values - where you define what 'previous' means as in the `partition by` and `order by` clauses - and then filter based on that:

```
select name, startdate, event
from (
  select name, startdate,
    case when lag_event is null or lag_event != event then event end as event
  from (
    select name, startdate, event,
      lag(event) over (partition by name order by startdate) as lag_event
    from t42
  )
)
where event is not null
order by name, startdate, event;

NAME       STARTDATE EVENT    
---------- --------- ----------
Ali        07-JAN-10 garage     
Ali        10-JAN-10 aircond    
Ali        14-JAN-10 garage     
Ali        15-JAN-10 yard       
Ali        16-JAN-10 dock
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/32901/1); or [with the intermediate steps](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/32901/2) so you can see what's happening. The innermost query has the 'lag' column added; the next layer out compares the current value with the lag value and only keeps it if it has changed; and the outer query excludes those that are null after that process - that is, it excludes those that have *not* changed.

Another approach to this kind of problem is to assign each contiguous run of values to a bucket and then find the first date for each bucket. You can assign the buckets with a trick using the `row_number` analytic function:

```
select name, startdate, event,
  row_number() over (partition by name, event order by startdate)
    - row_number() over (partition by name order by startdate) as chain
from t42
order by name, startdate, event;
```

And then use that as a subquery, with an aggregate to just get the first date you're interested in:

```
select name, min(startdate) as startdate, event
from (
  select name, startdate, event,
    row_number() over (partition by name, event order by startdate)
      - row_number() over (partition by name order by startdate) as chain
  from t42
)
group by name, event, chain
order by name, startdate, event;

NAME       STARTDATE EVENT    
---------- --------- ----------
Ali        07-JAN-10 garage     
Ali        10-JAN-10 aircond    
Ali        14-JAN-10 garage     
Ali        15-JAN-10 yard       
Ali        16-JAN-10 dock
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/32901/3)

Comment: @PrikshitConc. - yes, it will work in SQL*Plus; why wouldn't it? It's just standard Oracle SQL syntax.